# extract text from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

i have a UIWebView loaded with a simple rtf file. (containing one line "THIS IS A TEST")

```
UIWebView* webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 400)];
[[self view] addSubview:webview];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"rtf"]isDirectory:NO]]];
NSString *html = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"all"];
NSLog (@"html:%@", html.debugDescription);
```

The "THIS IS A TEXT" line appears inside the UIWebView correctly.
Does anyone know if it's somehow possible to extract that line of text (or more) to an NSString or some other accessible container ?

I know there is:

```
NSString *html = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

but that (obviously) doesn't work here. any ideas ? I'm basically trying to (fake) convert a rtf file to an NSString on iOS. 
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried document.body.innerHTML?

Comment: yes. and document.body.innerText . both come back blank.

Comment: Are you waiting till the page has loaded before calling stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:?

Comment: actually, you were right. I had to implement webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method and then I started to get some html results inside of it. sleep(int) was not the way to go. you should change this to an aswer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out `document.documentElement.innerText` is the way to go. Gets me the plain text right away.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of fetching html from UIWebView, and again apply extra efforts to convert html into plain text we can directly use below code to fetch text content from UIWebView:

```
NSString *plainText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.textContent"];
```

It saves your extra efforts for converting html into plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually had to do something similar in the past. Maybe not the most elegant, but here is what worked for me:

I would load the text from the file in to an HTML page (you can do this with javascript from inside the UIWebView, or you can do it from Objective-C creating a javascript method to call using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString). Then you can run the method call you outlined above, which should work fine, or you can create a custom method in Javascript that would capture and return the text to the Objective-C code. Here, it is stored as a string and is ready to go.

Comment: I don't know javascript. Was your solution for a rtf input format ?